# CakePHP: one-to-one using saveAll

Tags: cakephp

If I have many one-to-one relationships and I have a form which allows the user to enter data for all of these, how do I ensure that only populated records are saved in the child tables. eg a User can have a postal and residential address - the Models are set up as hasOne and belongsTo. If I display a form which allows entry of User data - how do I ensure (using saveAll) that an associated record in postalAddress or residentalAddress is ONLY created if those fields are filled in.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't think your relationships are setup correctly. If a `User` can have a postal and residential address, that's two addresses potentially. This will mean that

`User` hasMany `Address`
`Address` belongsTo `User`

You will need to create these relationships in your model. [More on relationships](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#relationship-types).

Secondly, you will need to add the fields into your form. I assume that you've completed this step.

In order to enforce data in the fields, you will want to create some validation rules. These will be on a per field basis in the model you want to validate. This means that you will want validation rules for the `User` in the `User` model, and your address validation in your `Address` model.

If you want to remove data from the data array before it is saved then you can use a model callback function to achieve this. I would recommend taking a look at `beforeSave()`. [Read about beforeSave](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave)

This callback will allow you to look at the data using `$this->data['User']['Address']['field']` to see if it's empty, and if it is, you can then prune it from the array.